# Top 3 os maiores números da lista e seus índices

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tenho a lista `[5, 7, 2]`. Preciso criar outra lista contendo os índices desta lista, ordenados de forma que o primeiro índice corresponda ao maior elemento da lista, o segundo corresponda ao segundo maior e assim por diante - ou seja, `[1, 0, 2]`.

Só consegui mostrar um número da lista por vez:

Índice : 1

Números: 7

O que eu não entendo é como montar o `for` para aparecer os índices e seus valores.

```
lista = [5, 7, 2]

ind_num = lista.index(max(lista))

print('Maior elemento: ',max(lista))

print('Indice: ', (ind_num))
```

Comment: Lucas, poderia ser mais claro? Cada elemento de uma lista (o que acredito que deva ser seu caso, possui um índice próprio, começando do zero). Edit: Entendi seu caso, irei elaborar  a resposta.

Comment: Os elementos de uma lista são os seus valores por lista = [5, 7, 2], os elementos dessa lista são 5, 7, 2 e sues incides começando pelo 0 ou seja os maiores estão nos índices 1, 0, 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma alternativa é:

```
lista = [5, 7, 2]
indices = sorted(range(len(lista)), key=lambda i: lista[i], reverse=True)
print(indices) # [1, 0, 2]
```

`range(len(lista))` cria uma sequência com todos os índices da lista (no caso, serão os números 0, 1 e 2).

Em seguida [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) ordena esses índices, mas em vez de levar em conta o seu valor, ele considera o respectivo valor dele na lista original - é isso que o *lambda* passado para `key` faz: para cada índice `i`, o valor que será levado em conta na ordenação é `lista[i]`.

Por fim, usamos `reverse=True` para que ele ordene do maior valor para o menor.

O resultado é a lista `[1, 0, 2]`.